# How to render a macro from a plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, macro

Im trying to render a site macro from my plugin, i’m getting the following error:

```
Argument 1 passed to Twig_Template::display() must be of the type array, object given, called in /path/to/file.php on line 51 and defined in "_macros/elements" at line 3
```

My service contains the following method:

```
public function renderSiteMacro($template, $macro, array $args)
{
    // Get the current template path
    $originalPath = craft()->path->getTemplatesPath();

    // Point Twig at the site templates
    craft()->path->setTemplatesPath(craft()->path->getSiteTemplatesPath());

    // Render the macro.
    $html = craft()->templates->renderMacro($template, $macro, $args);

    // Restore the original template path
    craft()->path->setTemplatesPath($originalPath);

    return TemplateHelper::getRaw($html);
}
```

And i'm calling it as follows:

```
$args = array(
    'entry' => $user,
    'layout' => 'friend'
);

$userHtml = craft()->logic->renderSiteMacro('_macros/elements', 'listing', $args);
```

The issue appears to be with the include line in my macro template file:

```
{% macro listing(config) %}
{% include "_macros/elements/listing" with config only %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Does anyone know what i'm missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Searching for uses of `renderMacro` in the Craft code I see that it is always called like:

```
craft()->templates->renderMacro('_includes/forms', 'textield', array(
  array(
    'name' => 'find',
    'placeholder' => Craft::t('Find'),
  )
));
```

So, what you want is probably

```
$html = craft()->templates->renderMacro($template, $macro, array($args));
```

Which is not at all clear from the [renderMacro](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/services/TemplatesService#renderMacro-detail) documentation...

Comment: Agreed, i'm just getting an empty var back from this call :( - No error which is good mind.

Comment: So it looks like the renderMacro function is throwing me a dummy, the issue looks to be with the returnJson function messing with the raw html that the rendermacro function is returning. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

The format of the [include tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html) is

```
{% include 'template' with {var1: value1, var2: value2} only %}
```

What you need after the `with` is an associative array (an array with keys and values).

In your specific case you want this:

```
{% include "_macros/elements/listing" with {config: config} only %}
```

Comment: At a twig level the config variable is an associative array in the same way the macros work in the the craft core. Isn't  it more likely the format of the $args variable??

Comment: I think you're right. Examples of renderMacro in the Craft code look like:
`renderMacro('template', 'macroName', array(array('key'=>'value')))`. So `renderMacro($template, $macro, array($args))`?